# How to write an sql query to copy only the column names from one table and paste it to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, copy

I have two existing tables, I would like to copy all the column names from sourcetable to destination table. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable (ColumnName)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SourceTable'
```

This copies only one column at at time. I would like to copy all the columns names at a time.

Comment: the destination table has what rows? and what rows are you mapping to copy?

Comment: I just want the column name to be copied to the destination table. I does not contain any data

Comment: Is the destination table already created or are you creating it on the fly? because you can do this using a select into...

Answer (score 0):

From what you are asking it seems like you need to use w3 schools for sql tutorials.

you can achieve what you're trying to do by...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable (ColumnName, ColumnName2, ColumnName3, ColumnName4)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME2, COLUMN_NAME3, COLUMN_NAME4 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SourceTable'
```

I am still very unclear what you are trying to do. are you trying to map the databases and is the destination table already created?

Comment: I have been trying to copy the rows from Apex interactive grid ROW_SELECTOR checkbox selected rows to another table. I am not sure how to write a query to select only the rows that are selected by the user

Comment: have a look at this blog https://blog.cloudnueva.com/apex-ig-processing-selected-records this might help